# what is the best way for saving cache data on a realtime sytem?

Tags: c++, algorithm, real-time

I have a server that recive data from a remote pc I need to save some data struce that contain my caclution data.
currently I save the data structure by dumping to hard disk per each update 
about 100 update per second and 800 byte each time.

in next step I need save seq number also for when that server restart say to boad what is last seq that my server recive
this can be 2 byte but this take can be 1000 update per sec for a file.

I want a to ask if this is good way stor cache data in this way? .what is other way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The file cache will very likely handle this, unless you flush all writes immediately to disk. So the answer is simple: just don't flush.